# Trying to change a faucet, there's a piece of metal that prevent me to use a basin wrench... What to do?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

There is this kind of tube that prevent me to use any kind of wrench to unscrew the nut in it. But without unscrewing it, I cannot get the faucet out of its place at all.
[image]
Is there a simple trick, or tool, that would allow me to go up there unscrew it. That tube is ~ 5 to 6 inch long.

Comment: That faucet probably came with a tool to install it. You need something similar to a deep well socket. Deep well sockets are only a few inches long though. One of the plumbing guys will come along with the correct name of the tool you need.

Comment: a crow's foot "spanner" that fits on a 3/8 socket extension would work... an example : https://www.amazon.com/19mm-Piece-Crows-Foot-Spanner/dp/B009ZX1IO0

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Eastman-45041-Plumber-Socket-Silver/dp/B00065DMHC. If you no longer have the tool that came wit it yiu will need something like these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[https://www.amazon.com/Moen-118305-Installation-Tool/dp/B002PB1JJS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002PB1JJS)

[image]

You need an extremely deep socket. Most faucet manufacturers make them, and they're often included with a new faucet. That metal collar makes it look like a standard basin wrench won't work, but it's worth a shot if you have one.

Comment: That's it! We went to the local hardware store, bought a new Moen faucet (that was the brand of the old one), got the tool and removed everything with it! Now, to return the Moen faucet we got only for the tool... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a universal faucet wrench but it may be too thick because of the shroud, my next set of tools is actually a set of sockets that looks like a chain saw wrench maybe 6 sizes they are hollow and each one is 2 sizes. These may be long enough to be able to get a wrench on , I will try to find a proper description and edit the answer.
I found part number 34a498 socket set on granger & amazon that is similar , this is not heavy duty but has gotten some nuts out in tight spaces like you have.